# 3-regular claw free graphs

Tags: graph-theory

A graph is said claw-free if it contains no induced subgraph isomorphic to $K_{1,3}$. Prove that every 3-regular claw-free graph has a 2-factor such that this 2-factor only has cycles of length 3 or 4.

I think that maybe if we consider the 2-factor with the maximum number of cycles, this could be the answer but I do not know how to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a vertex $a$ in the $3$-regular graph and its three neighbours $b,c,d$. By claw-freeness, there must be an edge between at least one pair out of $b,c,d$. Say there is an edge $bc$, then $b$ and $c$ have exactly one other neighbour each, $e$ and $f$ respectively.

If all of $d,e,f$ are distinct, we include the cycle $abc$ in the $2$-factor; we call the subgraph induced by $abc$ a type A fragment. If two of $d,e,f$ are the same, say $e=f$, the vertex $e=f$ is adjacent to exactly one other vertex $g$, and we include the cycle $abec$ in the $2$-factor; the subgraph induced by $abec$ is a type B fragment.

Since the choice of $a$ was arbitrary, every vertex in the $3$-regular claw-free graph belongs to a fragment, so the graph may be partitioned into fragments that can each be covered by one $3$- or $4$-cycle. This proves the existence of a $2$-factor with only cycles of length $3$ and $4$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do not completely get the part " every vertex in the 3-regular claw-free graph belongs to a fragment", because, in a 2-factor, each vertex must come in just one of the cycles.

Comment: @Not_Founded For every vertex I can define a fragment that contains it, by the given process.

Comment: How? I mean for example for vertex a, if we have a type A fragment, how will we cover the vertex d? in this situation a (as a neighbor of d) is covered and we can not use it again.

Comment: @Not_Founded Vertex $d$ belongs to another fragment.

Comment: It is not really clear for me why! could you please give an example?

Comment: @Not_Founded I have given you enough examples already. For a type A fragment imagine that edges $ad,be,cf$ are only half-edges - loose connections - and that you connect type A and B fragments at their half-edges to produce any $3$-regular claw-free graph.

Comment: thanks, I think it is clearer now